# How to update and delete data from table in MainActivity in SQLITEOPENHELPER

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite, main-activity

Question is how display data from user id.

I am Created a database for students with fields Name,surname,marks and I did insert and view Sucesfully but I don't know how to do Update and Delete please help. here i want to do update and delete based on ID I did an Update coading in DAbaseclas but when i going to declare in MainActivity i got an error here i attach an image

My databasehandler class

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME="students.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME="student_table";
private static final String COL_1="ID";
private static final String COL_2="NAME";
private static final String COL_3="SURNAME";
private static final String COL_4="MARKS";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL( "Create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,SURNAME TEXT,MARKS INTEGER)");
    Log.d("oncreate","Table Was Created"); }@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
public boolean insertdata(String name,String surname,String marks)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,marks);
    long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
public Cursor getalldata(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor res=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;

}public int Update(int id,String Name,String surname,string marks){
SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
contentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
contentValues.put(COL_4,marks);return db.update(TABLENAME, contentValues,"ID=?",new String[] {id});}
```

Comment: your `update` method expects 4 arguments and you are passing only 3, what about `id` you are not passing that in `update` method

Comment: in database handler ??

Comment: yes in your image, the error is because you are not passing required arguments

Comment: thx but how to perform and i have a doubt in that when i gave id and Click Show datas want to be loadin Editbox fields when i click Update button database want to be update how can we done this

Answer (score 1):

In MainActivity.java :

```
 private void deleteData() {
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer deleteAccount = databaseHelperAdapter.deleteAccount(tvEmail.getText().toString());
                if (deleteAccount > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Data Deleted ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Data Not Deleted ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void UpdateData() {
        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String gender = genderspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String image = imUserPhoto.toString();

                boolean isUpdate = databaseHelperAdapter.updateData(tvEmail.getText().toString(),
                        etFname.getText().toString(),
                        etLname.getText().toString(),
                        etPassword.getText().toString(), gender, image);
                if (isUpdate == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Data Updated ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Data Not Updated ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

In Database.java :

```
  public boolean updateData(String name, String fname, String lname, String password, String gender, String image) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.EMAIL, email);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.FNAME, fname);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.LNAME, lname);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD, password);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.GENDER, gender);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.IMAGE, image);
        sqLiteDatabase.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, DatabaseHelper.EMAIL + " =? ", new String[]{email});
        return true;

    }

    public int deleteAccount(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseHelper.EMAIL + " =?", new String[]{email});

    }
```

To Fetch the data from Id :

```
 public Cursor getData(int id){
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null );
      return res;
   }
```

Comment: thanks but when gave id and click show the details want to be load how can we do that (ie) "show" button click event

Comment: You need to fetch the data from user id and then toast that data.

Comment: if my above answer is correct and satisfied what you want ..than  accept it.

Comment: ji the code is crt i accepted but doubt is when i gave the id no in edittext and when i click show button the datas in sql on current id want to be diaplay how can we perform that

Comment: Check my Updated answer.. Don't expect that i m going to complete your whole code. .do by yourself..if you got error then only post.

Comment: no the details was updated No error but the show button was Not Working that y i asked thanks

Comment: plz say wht we want to do in Main Activity i got a error :( @Namik